# Async behavior in views in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, single-page-application

After some research I decided to start a new website in ASP.NET Core MVC. I understand the pages are rendered server side instead of a SPA application where more processing is done on the client. The views in general are pretty simple (basic forms/tables and such) so I elected not to use any complicated front end framework like React/Angular to reduce complexity. I'm using a standard ASP.NET Core MVC project with Razor syntax in my views.

Although my views are simple, I have some reasonable requirements I want to integrate into the app. For example, when rendering a table of data for the user, where that data needs to be retrieved from the database, currently I'm doing this in an MVC controller action. The controller task type is asynchronous, but I use await in the action for my repository before returning the view model (containing the returned database content) to to the view.

This results in loading different pages taking a long time, since I'm sometimes making multiple API calls or database queries *before* returning the view, since all that data is included in the view model and processed in the controller action.

I'd prefer to load the web page and display a loading icon (or something similar) in the table where data will be located. Then, after the database call succeeds the table will be populated. This allows the page to be loaded and table content (for example) to be populated when it's available. This seems much more possible/common with a SPA application. **Did I choose the wrong architecture or is there a way to accomplish similar (very reasonable) results in views in ASP.NET Core MVC?**

Comment: You can always choose to call the controller action method via Ajax from the view. You can have controller action method which will return json result or partial view . The main action would just render the view will the minimal html and once the view is rendered you can trigger Ajax call to other actions to get json data or partial view. You can show waiting icon or loading image until Ajax call is completes. Once you receive data from Ajax call you can render it.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I thought about that as well. I was hoping there was a more native ASP.NET Core MVC way to approach this, but it might just require Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: You need to find out where the time is going. MVC Core, either standard pages or the suggested approach above  work very well and are usually fast. My experience is that a lot developers don't get the best out of the database in terms of table model and data retrieval. For index views, consider using a database view that is efficient rather than a direct select on a table which might be slower, especially where you join to other tables